# gumroad overlay with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I can't seem to get overlay to work with rails turbolinks.

It works when the page is first loaded, but doesn't work when navigating using turbolinks. That is, when a page is loaded via turbolinks, the gumroad link takes you to the gumroad site when it should show the overlay.

Any ideas?

I've tried this code:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
  //load gumroad
  $.getScript("https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js")
      .done(function() {
        console.log("loaded gumroad");
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log("gumroad loading failed");
      });
});
```

I've also tried the regular script src in the html head.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add:

> Gumroad.init();

to your `page:change` event.